# Wrong layout on (x)large display

Tags: android, android-layout

I recently started creating apps for android and wanted to test layouts for different screen sizes. Since I've got no android device I created to virtual ones with AVD:

1. 240 dpi, No width or height specifications (for phones)
2. 160 dpi, 800 x 1280 (for tablets)

Since I just finished a tutorial I just edited my app so that the directory looks like this:

```
res/
    layout/
        activity_main.xml

    layout-large/
        activity_main.xml
```

layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout-large/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send_large"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

The two different string ressources contain different strings, so what I expected it to do is to display the one on large displays and the other on everything else. What it does is just using the .xml file from the "layout" folder on any device.

So I did some research and tried to rename "layout-large" to "layout-xlarge" and finally to "layout-sw600dp". Didn't work either.
Both devices run on Android 4.1.
And yes, I did make sure that eclipse launched the app on the correct device.

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put followin

```
<?xml ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

in **res/ layout/ activity_main.xml**

AND  CREATE
**res/ layout-hdpi/ activity_main.xml**

```
                     ^^^^
```

Put followin

```
<?xml ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send_large"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

in **res/ layout-hdpi/ activity_main.xml**

```
           ^^^^
```

Comment: I did, that's what I wanted to make clear with the comments and the sentence under the xml. I guess that's what I get for being lazy. I'll clear it up in the question.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I still wonder why the rest didn't.

Comment: Now that really got me wondering. As I wrote I set the display density to 160dpi which is mdpi as far as I know. So why does it take the hdpi layout?

Comment: Does above code properly written at your side? // And yes, Just clean once your project.

Comment: I did everything like you said. I cleaned the project and even deleted all user data (just to make sure, you never know...). Same result. The tablet with the mdpi display shows the button of layout-hdpi/activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can define different string values for different screen sizes using the same folder hierachy for the values

```
res/
 |-values/
 |-values-large/
```

So in for the same string id in a single layout the value will change with the screen size

I'm not sure if the problem come from this point but it may be ...

Hope it helps